# What's wrong with this dict comprehension including django objects (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)?

Tags: python, django-models, dictionary-comprehension

here is from Django:

```
def get_temp_data(nid = None,qid = None,data = None):
    from core_apps.models import Temps
    temp_data = Temps.objects.all()
    if nid != None:
        temp_data = temp_data.filter(nid=nid)
    if qid != None:
        temp_data = temp_data.filter(qid=qid)
    if data != None:
        temp_data = temp_data.filter(data__gte=data)
    temp_data.order_by('id_field')
    return temp_data
```

here is a dict comprehension including OR Mapper objects from above function:

```
record_for_nid = {obj.qid: obj.data for obj in get_temp_data(nid, None, None) if obj.data != 0.0}
```

`record_for_nid` runs perfectly fine on the regular situation but does not on crontab. A little suspicion is that sublime text error checker picks up an error on the "for" in this list comprehension. What's wrong with the code? And how to fix it?

Comment: You have a dictionary comprehension, not a list comprehension. What is the full traceback of the error? Dictionary comprehensions require Python 2.7 or up; your syntax is otherwise perfectly valid.